# Explanation about Comparator in a Collection

Tags: java, collections, comparator

When you add a Comparator to a Collection how does it work?

For example, if I used a Comparator on a Treeset

```
TreeSet<Market> tree = new TreeSet<>(new Market().new Comp());

for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {
    tree.add(new Market(i, i + 1));
}

public class Comp implements Comparator<Market> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Market A, Market B) {
        return A.w - B.w;
    }
}
```

Does it treat Market A as something that already exists in the Tree and B as the new Market that is added to the tree? or is it otherwise?

```
public class Market {
    int w, h;

    public Market(int w, int h) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "w: " + w + ", h: " + h;
    }

    public class Comp implements Comparator<Market> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Market A, Market B) {
            return A.w - B.w;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "How does it work?" - see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-) "Does it treat Market A as something that already exists in the Tree..." Why does it matter to you?

Comment: You aren't adding a `Comparator` to a collection in this code. You are specifying a `Comparator` as a parameter of the constructor; but that's not the same thing.

Comment: @D.B. case A is in the tree and  B is added , the decision made by the method  case is 1 is putting A in the left side and B on the right side (IndexA<IndexB). case B is in  the tree and A is added ,the decision made by the method  case is 1 is putting B in the left side and A on the right side (IndexB<IndexA).

Answer (score 1):

That's an implementation detail. The implementation of `TreeSet` (or rather the implementation of the backing `TreeMap`) can decide as it sees fit whether `A` or `B` is an element already in the `Set` when it calls `compare`.

Your implementation of `compare` shouldn't be affected by this implementation detail.

Looking at the JDK 8 implementation, I see that the first argument (A) happens to be the key (or element) you wish to add (or check if it's already present), and the second argument is a key (or element) already in the `TreeMap` (or `TreeSet`) :

```
final Entry<K,V> getEntryUsingComparator(Object key) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        K k = (K) key;
          -----------
    Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;
    if (cpr != null) {
        Entry<K,V> p = root;
        while (p != null) {
            int cmp = cpr.compare(k, p.key);
                                  -
            if (cmp < 0)
                p = p.left;
            else if (cmp > 0)
                p = p.right;
            else
                return p;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I played with the treeSet in my eclipse and it looks like he treats A as the existing elemnet, but i am not sure about it . Maybe i dont realy understand how Comparator works

Comment: @gabi939 I don't know how you determined that it uses A as the existing element. Either you are wrong, or you are using a different Java version having a different implementation. Either way, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: this is the output of my code [w: 0, h: 1, w: 1, h: 2, w: 2, h: 3]

Comment: @gabi939 without context, I have no idea what this output means.

Comment: this is the output of my code [w: 0, h: 1, w: 1, h: 2, w: 2, h: 3] in case B was inside of the tree and A was added let us say that compare returned 1. So it should put A on the left side of the tree.

 In my case, I put all my objects in ascending order, and in case A was the added elements according to my code it should put always in the right side(because compare returns value>0).

so it should print it in ad decending order

Comment: @gabi939 perhaps if you included in the question the code that produces this output (or is it something you see in the debugger?), I'll be able to understand what you mean. I have no idea what these `w` and `h` values stand for.